# Root the Samsung Infuse (i997)

Tags: rooting, samsung-infuse-4g

Does anyone know how to root the Samsung Infuse (i997)?
I have tried two methods already:

- Visionary
- Samsung One Click Root

Visionary simply doesn't work, while the Samsung One Click Root manages to push the update.zip to the sdcard, but the Samsung recovery rejects it based on signature verification failure, as it is the FroYo supplied recovery.

I am hesitant to try [Project Voodoo](http://project-voodoo.org/), because I'm afraid to brick the device with a non-compatible Odin tar image.

Comment: Please do not put tags like "SOLVED" in the title. Accepting an answer changes the look of the question in the list. By virtue of there being an accepted answer says that the issue was solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED:

While the rageagainstthecage exploit is not working with the Infuse, you can root it with the psneuter exploit. Easiest way to do it is with the [SuperOneClick](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=803682) application.